# How to access function calls for an upgraded contract?

Tags: solidity

I followed [OpenZeppelin's HardHat process](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/hardhat-upgrades) for writing upgradeable contracts.

1. Write an implementation contract (example.sol) with upgradeable Initializers
2. Write a script to deploy it within Hardhat that deploys proxy
3. Write exampleV2.sol and deploy new proxy

I have a few questions regarding this

1. What is TransparentUpgradeableProxy contract that was deployed from deployer address?
2. What is the ProxyAdmin and how is it different to #1?
3. How do I make function calls to `example.sol` from ProxyAdmin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is an "owned" contract that blindly forwards requests to an implementation at another address.
2. Proxy admin is allowed to change the address of the implementation. This is how an upgrade occurs.
3. Use the ABI for Example.sol *at the address of the TransparentUpgradeableProxy*. It uses `delegateCall` and basically forwards inputs to the implementation, Example.sol, then it returns whatever came back, so the proxy is a work-alike for the implementation. It's simply a matter of instantiating `Example.at(<proxyAddress)`.

There are subtle things to be wary of when using this pattern, so be sure to do your homework. In particular, do not set any state variable values in your constructor in Example.sol. Use `function initialize()` instead, with `initializer` modifier from OpenZeppelin's Initializable.sol.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob, A few further questions if I may

1 – My transparentupgradeableproxy has no instance Example.sol if that's what you meant, am I looking at the wrong place? When I load this address in Remix, I get "No compiled contracts" error. // 2 – Could you point me to an example of #3? // 3 – ExampleV2.at(proxy) should also work once I upgrade right?

Comment: Maybe post the contract and deployment script as a new question. I'd be guessing.